# Filter data in Shiny application and display it in another tab

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app

## Server.R

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)

function(input, output) {
  
  values <- reactiveValues()
  
  Post <- c("", "")
  list2 <- c(12,13)
  df <- data.frame(Post, list2)
  
  Post <- c("Ba", "Ba")
  list2 <- c(12,13)
  df2 <- data.frame(Post, list2)
  
  output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({
  
  rhandsontable(df, width = 550, height = 300) %>%    
      hot_col(col = "Post", type = "dropdown")
  })
  
  saveData <- function(){
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    return(finalDF)
  }
  
  output$contentFinal <- renderRHandsontable(
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
  )
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, saveData())

}
```

## UI.R

```
library(rhandsontable)
fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Summary", rHandsontableOutput('contents'),
                           actionButton("saveBtn", "Save changes")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Tab",
                           rHandsontableOutput('contentFinal'))
                  
                  
                  
      )
      
    )
  )
)
```

I would like to create functionality that when I press save in summary tab all a dataframe with all value that are not empty (so edited) are shown in the "tab" tab.

However when I create a table with:

```
 output$contentFinal <- renderRHandsontable(
        finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
      )
```

It's not coming back in UI. Any thoughts on what Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)


ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Summary", rHandsontableOutput('contents'),
                           actionButton("saveBtn", "Save changes")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Tab",
                           rHandsontableOutput('contentFinal'))



      )

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  Post <- c("", "")
  list2 <- c(12,13)
  df <- data.frame(Post, list2)

  Post <- c("Ba", "Ba")
  list2 <- c(12,13)
  df2 <- data.frame(Post, list2)

  output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(df, width = 550, height = 300) %>%    
      hot_col(col = "Post", type = "dropdown")
  })

  saveData <- function(){
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    print(finalDF)
    return(finalDF)
  }

  output$contentFinal <- renderRHandsontable({
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    rhandsontable(finalDF)}
  )
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, saveData())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You have made two mistakes:

1. You forgot additional brackets: `{}` while calling `output$contentFinal`
2. You forgot to call `rhandsontable()` function in `output$contentFinal`

So your call should look like this:

```
 output$contentFinal <- renderRHandsontable({
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    rhandsontable(finalDF)}
  )
```

[UPDATE]

Remove empty rows in `output$contentFinal`:

```
output$contentFinal <- renderRHandsontable({
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    finalDF <- finalDF[!apply(finalDF, 1, function(x) any(x=="")),] # remove empty rows
    rhandsontable(finalDF)}
```

`apply` gives each row to any, which checks if the expression `x==""` is true.

Comment: many thanks. Go it working now! Another question I have. Another thing I want to do it to filter the data and make sure that only the filtered data comes back in the tab "Tab". So let's say I edit the table in summary and classify 2 of the 3 records as "Boodschappen". Then how can I make sure only a filter of these records appear in Tab?

Comment: How you wanna filter data?on what kind of base?

Comment: What you mean by classify 2 of the 3 records as "Boodschappen"? You will classify it by filling up Post column in summary Tab Table?

Comment: Check out my update, if i understood you correctly you wanna remove the empty rows from the `output$contentFinal`

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer! Not working completely yet though... Ill post a new question